# Does the ice created by Shape Water have higher durability than regular ice?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips

If Shape Water is used to freeze water into ice, in a particular shape (e.g. a small wall to use as cover, a battering ram to bash down a door, or an ice lockpick), does that ice object have the durability of regular non-magical ice? Or is it more resistant to shattering, chipping, and other such physical damage?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## RAW it is normal ice

RAW the ice would have no special properties. Generally, if the spell doesn't say it does something, it doesn't do that thing. In this case, it says

> You freeze the water, provided that there are no creatures in it. The water unfreezes in 1 hour.

**It does not say that the result of the freezing imparts any kind of special properties** besides the ice remaining frozen for an hour (which might not be normal for ice). It is normal water, but it is now simply frozen.

This fact does not change when you shape it either as that ability also does not say anything about imparting any quality but shape and moment to the water.

> You cause the water to form into simple shapes and animate at your direction. This change lasts for 1 hour.

Note: that you are **not creating magical ice** here. You are using a magic effect to freeze normal mundane water into ice which is mundane in all of its qualities except the ones specifically called out in the spell.

Comment: RAI, would you say that water frozen this way would melt in less than an hour in, say, an oven, or take longer to melt (if ever) in an open snowfield? RAW, it would still melt in an hour in either case, but that suggests to me that there is indeed some kind of magical effect acting on the water that is different that the way water normally behaves.

Comment: There's definitely a magic effect here, but to my reading the ice is definitely not magical. It never even says the word ice. It just says that it freezes water. Normal water. As I read it, the water will remain frozen for an hour, but after that would probably return to unfrozen water. Regardless, the important thing to note is that you can't just pretend the spell does something other than what it says. It freezes water. Nothing else.